Integrate Bootstrap 5 with Rollup
I try to integrate bootstrap with a rollup package but I keep getting several errors. I was wondering if there is a way to make it work, even if I have to change my structure.
Structure:

src/index.ts
import './assets/scss/_main.scss';
import { Table } from './components';
export default Table;

export * from './hooks';
export * from './helpers';
export * from './types';
export * from './constants';

src/assets/scss/_main.scss
// 1. Configuration and helpers
@import './variables';
@import './mixins';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-utilities.scss';

src/rollup.config.js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      terser(),
      postcss({
        modules: true
      }),
      scss(),
      sass(),
      image()
    ]
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/cjs/types/src/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts.default()],
    external: [/\.css$/]
  }
];

The error I usually get is:
[!] RollupError: Could not resolve "./assets/scss/_main.scss" from "dist/cjs/types/src/index.d.ts"
